# MongoDB-esq SQL query

Tags: sql, mongodb, postgresql

Let's say I have a master table which has 2, 1:n relationships with 2 other tables. e.i a group will have many channels and many users.

In MongoDB I could get a comprehensive JSON representation of a group with a **single** query. e.i.

```
{
  group_id: n,
  display_name: n,
  followers: n,
  channels: [
    {
      id: n,
      name: m
    },
    {
      id: n,
      name: m
    }...
  ],
  users: [
    {
      id: n,
      name: m
    },
    {
      id: n,
      name: m
    }...
  ]
}
```

Is there a nice way to get a result similar to this in pg instead of having to query separately for the related **channels** and **users** that belong to a group.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the JSON commands made available in postgres. The following query helped achieve the result above:

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
  select id, followers, image_url,
  (
    select json_agg(row_to_json(s))
    from (
        select channel_id, channel_name
        from public.post_channel
        where group_id=groups.id
    ) s
  ) as channels
  from public.groups
) t 
where id = '2677abe1-2164-4646-875b-af65a5ba1786';
```

which gave the result:

```
{
  "id": "2677abe1-2164-4646-875b-af65a5ba1786",
  "followers": 1,
  "image_url": "https://host.com/HomePageMockUp.PNG",
  "channels": [
    {
      "channel_id": "b0767288-f522-490a-a90f-93df0694355b",
      "channel_name": "Announcements"
    },
    {
      "channel_id": "075bba44-42c0-42b2-845f-4912cc34e762",
      "channel_name": "General"
    }
  ]
}
```